# Decomposition of an exponential and the digit in the one's place of the answer

Tags: linear-algebra

The digit in the one's place of the number [image] corresponds to:

I can see that this problem isn't difficult at all, yet I would like to know the reasoning behind its answer (which is 9). I first thought I could try and decompose the exponent to [image], yet I dont really see how this would help me. Can someone please explain how to get the answer for me?

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at the one's place of various powers of 23:
$$
\begin{align}
23^1&\equiv3\pmod{10}\\
23^2&\equiv9\pmod{10}\\
23^3&\equiv7\pmod{10}\\
23^4&\equiv1\pmod{10}\\
23^5&\equiv3\pmod{10}\\
\end{align}
$$
We can see that the one's digit has a period of 4.
Now we want to cycle the list. Since the one's digit repeats every 4, we can do
$$
2014\equiv2\pmod{4}.
$$
The answer is the second one in our list, 9.